# I can't understand the algebraic simplification below

Tags: fractions

I can't understand the last step of simplification in the following algebraic expression.

I am aware that $\sqrt{3}=3^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Can't see how they get the $6$ in the denominator, and how $\sqrt{3}$ gets to the numerator. Any help will be appreciated.

p.s. this is from a mathematics text book. last step of a derivative calculation.

$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} =\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$ \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$$
As can be seen I have multiplied the fraction by $1 = \sqrt{3} \ / \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thanks Kayle. Perfect. The power of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have  $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$
=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt{3}\sqrt 3}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2\times 3}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt 3}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\times1=\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\times\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}=\frac{1\times\sqrt3}{2\sqrt3\times\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2\times3}=\frac{\sqrt3}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

The two tricks to get square roots out of fraction denominators are:

1. If you have a fraction which looks like: $$A=\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{b}}$$
   then $$A=1\cdot A = \frac{a-\sqrt b}{a-\sqrt b}\cdot \frac{x}{a+\sqrt b} = \frac{x(a-\sqrt b)}{(a-\sqrt b)(a+\sqrt b)} - \frac{x(a-\sqrt b)}{a^2-b}$$
2. If you have a fraction which looks like $$B=\frac{x}{\sqrt c}$$ then $$B=1\cdot b = \frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt c}\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt c} = \frac{x\sqrt c}{\sqrt c \sqrt c} = \frac{x\sqrt c}{c}$$

Comment: Thanks 5xum for going beyond and explaining how to get the square root out if it were accompanied by another term, using difference of two squares. Appreciate it.

Comment: @K.Nav My pleasure. If the answer is useful, you can also accept (or upvote) it.